# Autonumbering upon keyboard press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an autonumbering when  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  and  <kbd>Enter</kbd> are pressed. My current problem is, when i start my autonumbering at the 3rd textbox, my 2nd textbox is getting affected. How can i retain the other values of my textbox? The textbox before them should not change their value.

Thank you.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.leg', function(e) {
  let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && (e.keyCode == 17 || e.keyCode == 13)) {
    //loop through all values...
    $(".leg").each(function(i) {
      if (i !== 0) {
        $(this).val(++value); //assign new value..
        $(this).trigger("change") //call your change event to handle further...
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="leg">
<input type="text" class="leg">
<input type="text" class="leg">
<input type="text" class="leg">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable to keep track of whether or not the `each` loop has crossed the target element and then only modify the input's value when it is true. This will make sure you only modify the inputs after the target.

See `runChange` in example:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.leg', function(e) {
  let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && (e.keyCode == 17 || e.keyCode == 13)) {
    //loop through all values...
    let runChange = false;
    $(".leg").each(function(i, el) {
      if (runChange) {
        $(this).val(++value); //assign new value..
        $(this).trigger("change") //call your change event to handle further...
      }
      if (e.target == el) runChange = true;
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="leg">
<input type="text" class="leg">
<input type="text" class="leg">
<input type="text" class="leg">
```

Comment: Saviour. <3 Thank you so much and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop checking of `0`'th input and change all inputs every time:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.leg', function(e) {
  let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  const inputIndex = $(this).index() - 1;
  if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && (e.keyCode == 17 || e.keyCode == 13)) {
    //loop through all values...
    $(".leg").each(function(i) {
      if (i !== inputIndex) {
        $(this).val(++value); //assign new value..
        $(this).trigger("change") //call your change event to handle further...
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="leg">
<input type="text" class="leg">
<input type="text" class="leg">
<input type="text" class="leg">
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I have tried your solution and it is not working. The same error occurs. The before textboxes are still affected.

https://prnt.sc/24lov3j

Comment: @Dark, I modified the answer to ignore the focused input.